# Replace character in multiple index

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a **String** like:

```
AB524D000000000000231200000001D0000000000000000524
```

The length of string is 50. Above string is one. this type of string may have lenght 250 ie. five string example:

```
AB524D000000000000231200000001D0000000000000000524AB524D000000000000231200000001D0000000000000000524AB524D000000000000231200000001D0000000000000000524AB524D000000000000231200000001D0000000000000000524AB524D000000000000231200000001D0000000000000000524.
```

Now my requirement is I need to change `D` to `C`.

I used following code to replace for one string:

```
String code = key.substring(0, 2);
String currency = key.substring(2, 5);
String type = key.substring(5, 6);
String amount = key.substring(6, 22);
String rate = key.substring(22, 30);
String type2 = key.substring(30, 31);
String rAmount = key.substring(31, 47);
String currency2 = key.substring(47, 50);


String finalReq = code + currency + "C" + amount + rate + "C" + rAmount + currency2;
```

I got following output:

```
AB524C000000000000231200000001C0000000000000000524
```

this is good for one string I mean 50 length string. But string length may 0-250 (string one to 5) but pattern is same like : **AB524D000000000000231200000001D0000000000000000524**.

Which is the best logic to fulfill my requirement ?.

**Note:** I can not do `string.replaceAll('D','C')` because my zeroth and first index has  character I mean it may have also **D**.

Comment: Just use `String#replace(char, char)`. It will replace all cases of the first character with the second. You could also use `String#replaceAll(String, String)` if there are special cases, which you can fulfil with a regex.

Comment: You reached `substring()` method before `replace()`?

Comment: @RohitJain Rohit jee I did not get you.

Comment: @KalathokiL.. I meant you should use `replace()` method for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that

```
replaceAll("\\G(.{5})D(.{24})D(.{19})", "$1C$2C$3")
```

should do the trick but I don't know if your string will only contain data in format you described or if you want to replace only `D` or any character that can be in places that `D` is.

---

`replaceAll` uses regex as first parameter, and String that can use results of that regex as second parameter. In regex

- `.` dot represents any character except new line
- `.{x}` represents series of any characters that is length `x` like `.{3}` can match `AbZ` or `1X9`,
- regex inside parenthesis `(...)` will create group, and each group has its unique number. This number can be used later for example in `replacement` String via `$x` where `x` is number of group
- so `(.{5})D(.{24})D(.{19})` will match any 5  characters (and store them in group 1), then `D` then 24 characters (and create store them in group 2) then `D` and lastly any 19 characters (and store them in group 3)
- in replacement `"$1C$2C$3"` I will use strings that ware matched in first group, then instead of `D` will put `C` then will include match from group 2, then again instead of `D` will put `C` and after that include last part of match (last 19 characters after second `D` stored in group 3)
- Also assure match could be done only every 50 characters from start of the string I will add `\\G` represents start of the string or previously match (so there can't be any characters between previous match and current match).

Comment: Sir, My one string has 5o length and I want to replace `D` to `C` only index **5** and **30** of my first string. If string has 100 length I mean (**there is two string**) I need to replace same index of second string also and so on. And my string will not be more than five.

Comment: @KalathokiL. OK then my updated answer should do what you want assuming that is is used only to strings you described.

Comment: Code worked but I have a question If you do not mind can you explain the code or any link will you provide

Comment: @KalathokiL. I added explanation but it is hard to explain regex in few sentences so [[here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)] is really good tutorial that can explain in more detail how regex work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use java's String [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) method.

```
String old = "AB524D000000000000231200000001D0000000000000000524AB524D000000000000231200000001D0000000000000000524AB524D000000000000231200000001D0000000000000000524AB524D000000000000231200000001D0000000000000000524AB524D000000000000231200000001D0000000000000000524";
String output = old.replace('D', 'C');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that every string is 50 char so :

```
     index = finalReq.length() % 50;
      for(int i = 0; i<index; i++){
        String code = key.substring(0 + 50 * i, 2 + 50 * i);
        String currency = key.substring(2 + 50 * i , 5 + 50 * i);
        ...

        replace ...

}
```

Comment: I am sure every string is 50 length